# Random forest regression, back transformation of the dependent variable

Tags: random-forest, logarithm

I'm fitting a random forest regression model on consumption data. This model give me better results if I use log(consumption expenditure) instead of consumption expenditure as dependent variable.
When I try to do a prediction I obtain very poor results if I do the Exp of predicted values. I haven't find any type of correction that I can do...
Any one know a precedure that can I applied to correct the baias that arraise from the back trasfomration?

Thanks.

Comment: Input, output, and transformation can help.  Are you using an open dataset, or can you use an open dataset as an effective analogy?  Can you tell us more about the nature of "consumption expenditure" such as what the R psych::describe gives.  Can you describe the parameters of your forest?  Max depth, number of trees, and library help in diagnosing.  Are you using ranger, randomForest, h2o, party, caret, or sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor?

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the problem? What’s wrong?